# Create SQL using variables

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a function that receives a an array from the $_POST function then uses the indexes and values contained in the indexes to create an SQL. My problem is that I can get the function to echo the SQL correctly but I'm unable to create a variable. My function is below

```
 function createcontactsArray($sql,Array $contactsArray){
         //array has already been cleaned from sql injections

        //delete null variables and the value of the submit button        
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if($value == ""||$value=="continue") {
                unset($contactsArray[$key]);
            }

        }

        echo "INSERT INTO users(";
        //create list of tables to use in the database
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                echo $key;
            } else                {
                echo $key.",";
            }

        }
        echo ') VALUES (';

        //create list of tables to use in the database
        //$newcontactsArray = array_values($contactsArray);
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                echo '"'.$value.'"';
            } else                {
               echo '"'.$value.'"'.",";
            }

        }

        echo ');';
```

}

If you run this script and pass it an associative array for example `$contacts = array("name"=>"Peter griffin","town"=>"Quahogn");`it will output the following `INSERT INTO users (name,contacts) VALUES ("Peter griffin","Quahog")`. However I want the function to create an sql like `$sql = INSERT INTO users (name,contacts) VALUES ("Peter griffin","Quahog")` so that to output I just say `echo $sql;` Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function createcontactsArray($sql,Array $contactsArray){
         //array has already been cleaned from sql injections

        //delete null variables and the value of the submit button        
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if($value == ""||$value=="continue") {
                unset($contactsArray[$key]);
            }

        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users(";
        //create list of tables to use in the database
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                $sql .= $key;
            } else                {
                $sql .= $key.",";
            }

        }
        $sql .= ') VALUES (';

        //create list of tables to use in the database
        //$newcontactsArray = array_values($contactsArray);
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                $sql .= '"'.$value.'"';
            } else                {
               $sql .= '"'.$value.'"'.",";
            }

        }

        $sql .= ');';

        return $sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't echo all the parts but collect them in a string variable. So, instead of:

```
echo 'Text';
echo $variable;
```

do something like

```
$output = 'Text';
$output .= $variable;
```

At the end of the function return that output with

```
return $output;
```

Note that `.=` concatenates the former value with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

here is the right way. *safe* and clean

```
function dbSet($fields,$source=array()) {
  global $mysqli;
  if (!$source) $source = &$_POST;
  $set='';
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($source[$field])) {
      $set.="`$field`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$source[$field])."', ";
    }
  }
  return substr($set, 0, -2); 
}
```

used like this

```
$query  = "UPDATE $table SET ".dbSet(array("name","contacts"));
```

note that you should always hardcode the allowed fieldnames, not get them from the $_POST, or site will be hacked in a matter of seconds.

with mysql this function can be used for either INSERT or UPDATE queries.

Comment: it is also perfectly SAFE. you should always hardcode the fieldnames, not get them from the POST, or site will be hacked in a matter of seconds. use $this->conn instead of $mysqli if it's a part of a class

Comment: what exactly is returned by 'return substr($set, 0, -2);'

Comment: the string without 2 last characters. removing a comma

Comment: Now look at a bad code using `global $mysqli;` causes ugly scoping issues especially when it comes to database connection. This has been well discussed several times .. but no one down voted you yet you down voted be because of something that was specifically written in PHP documentation

Answer (score 0):

```
function createcontactsArray($sql,Array $contactsArray){
         //array has already been cleaned from sql injections
         $sql = '';
        //delete null variables and the value of the submit button        
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if($value == ""||$value=="continue") {
                unset($contactsArray[$key]);
            }

        }

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO users(";
        //create list of tables to use in the database
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                $sql .= $key;
            } else                {
                $sql .= $key.",";
            }

        }
        $sql .= ') VALUES (';

        //create list of tables to use in the database
        //$newcontactsArray = array_values($contactsArray);
        foreach ($contactsArray as $key => $value) {

            if ($value == end($contactsArray))                {
                $sql .= '"'.$value.'"';
            } else                {
               $sql .= '"'.$value.'"'.",";
            }

        }

        $sql .= ');';

        echo $sql;
```

Comment: Don worry. I saved u with an upvote to take u to zero. Your code works

Comment: Thank you @Ukavi. Nice to share